# GameManagerCompunet.MoveToNextStage()'is ininaccessible due to its protection level

Tags: c#, css, unity-game-engine

[**i get error on this line,i use inheritance on MoveToNextStage Can someone help me **](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pC92g.png)

Answer (score 0):

The error is trying to say to you that you are trying to access a variable with a more constrained level of protection. This is about your game manager access modifier, you probably had set it to private and are trying to access it in inheritance, verify if this is private and change it to protect, remember if you do not have an access modifier, c# by default set it to private

Comment: could u show me how to change it to protect?or reference for me to read?

Comment: You haven't shared your MoveToNextStage(...) code, but I'll suppose that this is typed equal to the NextStage(..) code, so you have - void NextState() - which is exactly equal to - private void NextStage() - then you need to change the modifier private, to protect if this method will be called only by itself or children in inheritance OR to public if this will be called by other classes

Comment: One last thing, next time, does not print your code, copy and paste using tags

Answer (score 0):

The error message tells you the problem. You can't access the method.

Make `MovetoNextStage` public or if the class is inherited, make it protected.

Comment: how i make it protected?can u show me the example how to fix  it or reference for me to read cause im newbe inC#,

Comment: @wita To make it protected you have to add the 'protected' accessor to it. If you're not worried about accessors, simply add 'public' the method declaration